# ASP.NET MVC: replace <%= Html.TextBox("name") %> with <asp:TextBox>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Because i want to set a Extender (Calendar from the AJAX Controls toolkit) on a textbox,
I have to change the code from

```
<%= Html.TextBox("name") %>
```

to

`<asp:TextBox ...>`

But how can i bind the attribute "name" on the  element?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using the jQuery [DatePicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker)?  It's much more friendly with MVC than the standard ASP controls and related extenders.

```
<%= Html.TextBox( "name" ) %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $('[name=name]').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, I have this:

<%= Html.TextBox("startDate") %>     
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $('#startDate').datepicker();
    });
 </script>  

I have standard jquery .js files in the Scripts folder. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's a jQuery UI widget.  You'll need to include at least jQuery UI core and the datepicker, if not all of the jQuery UI code (and CSS).

Comment: Yes, that worked! I will post my answer. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use the asp.net Ajax Beta to create a client side Calendar.

See here:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20Calendar%20Control.ashx

Strangely this version of the asp.net ajax library uses JQuery as well.

I would personally use the JQuery version... But the new asp.net ajax library is trying to evolve so that it works better with 'pure' html and asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I included the js from the google api, also the css.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" class="ui-theme" />
```

Then set the datepicker like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#startDate").datepicker();
});
</script>
```